# Send_mail in Django, works in shell, works locally, not in view

Tags: django, email, send

I'm not even sure how to debug this: I'm using send_mail in one of my views in Django. It works fine when using the app locally (using the same SMTP settings I use in production), and it works fine from the shell in production (again, using the same settings). But when I actually use the app in production, the message doesn't send. Any idea how to troubleshoot?

I won't paste in the whole view, but here's the relevant section.

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    message, form = decideform(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        invitation.status = form.cleaned_data['status']
        invitation.save()
        message, form = decideform(request.POST)
        update = 'Thank you for updating your status.'

        # Send an email confirming their change
        subject = 'Confirming your RSVP [%s %s]' % (invitation.user.first_name, invitation.user.last_name)
        body = message + ' Remember, the URL to update or change your RSVP is http://the.url%s.' % invitation.get_absolute_url()
        send_mail(subject, body, 'rsvp@mydomain.com', ['rsvp@mydomain.com', invitation.user.email], fail_silently=True)
```

And here's the relevant bits from my local_settings file, with salient details altered for security's sake:

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'mail.mydomain.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'rsvp@mydomain.com'
DEFAULT_FROM_USER = 'rsvp@mydomain.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'p4ssw0rd'
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Have you tried using `fail_silently=False` and looking for any `SMTPException`?

Comment: Thank you, César! I did try it with the fail_silently flag set to False (locally, in the production shell, and from the app in production), and caught no SMTPExceptions at any point. (I'm assuming that the app in production would write that exception to the error log.)

Answer (score 0):

Check permissions. It could be that you have permissions to run send_mail, but the app doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue. 3 years after :)
copying the code of send_mail inline fixed it but I still don't know why

```
        connection = django.core.mail.get_connection(username=None, password=None, fail_silently=False)
        mail = django.core.mail.message.EmailMessage('hello', 'world', 'test@gmail.com', ['test@gmail.com'],                                              connection=connection)
        mail.send()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try django-sendgrid instead which is very easy to configure.Use settings like this

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = "sgbackend.SendGridBackend"
SENDGRID_USER = 'xxxxxx'
SENDGRID_PASSWORD = 'xxxxxx'
EMAIL_PORT = 1025
```